# Calling: GetRespondentEmail Specific

Tags: javascript, forms

The following code is used to send an email to the respondent of a google form. The `onsubmit` call is from the spreadsheet that stores the responses.

I am not sure how to get the forms ID to use the solution given in several other places. Basically I just need to know how to call the `getRespondentEmail()`. I've tried calling it using `FormApp.getActive()` but I read that only works when you are working in the form it's self.

If you want to offer a solution that requires using the form ID, an explanation of how to get the ID would be great.

```
var GetUserEmail = getRespondentEmail().

var subject = "Skiver Production Report Successfully Submitted";
var textbody = "You have successfully submitted a Skiver Production Report. Do not reply to this email as it is not monitored.";
var message = "You have succesfully submitted a Skiver Production Report. Do not reply to this email as it is unmoinitored." ;

var cc = "techlab@worldwidefoam.com";
var sendername = "Quality Function";

GmailApp.sendEmail("bob@notArealemail.com", subject, textbody, {
    cc: cc,
    name: sendername,
    htmlBody: message
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the id of an element you can simply use the `document.getElementById(arg)` method. For example:

```
var myForm = document.getElementById("ID");
```

For simply calling `getRespondentEmail` you just place `getRespondentEmail()` in your code. Your first line is doing this correctly but the `.` at the end needs to be removed or replaced with a `;`, which is likely causing your error:

```
var GetUserEmail = getRespondentEmail(); // replace . with ;
```

Lastly if you would like to use `getRespondentEmail()` anywhere make sure it is in a global scope. Meaning it's not defined in any functions or closures.

Comment: I have replaced the . at the end of GetUserEmail. When I try and run the function I get this error message.   ReferenceError: "getRespondentEmail" is not defined. (line 3, file "")

Comment: I understand your reference to getElementById(arg) but how do I access the form's data to replace the document portion?   I.e  DriveApp.getElementbyId  or  FormApp.getElementById?

Comment: @AndrewCook You don't need to replace the `document` part, just using `document` will work fine. Also where is `getRespondentEmail()` defined? Like I mentioned you need it to be defined globally.

Comment: getResponseEmail() is a method of the FormResponse class defined in Apps Script.

Comment: @AndrewCook Then do `FormResponseInstance.getResponseEmail()` where `FormResponseInstance` is and instance of the class `FormResponse`.